# jQuery UI Slider to find id on document ready?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have the situation to prepopulate stored value from hidden element in [jquery ui slider](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/API/1.8/Slider) based on its id as like below,

```
jQuery(function(){
    if(jQuery("input[name=color_overlay_nav_bar]").val() != ''){ 
                   jQuery(".slider_global_style_overlay ").slider({
                       create: function(event, ui) {
                            console.log(jQuery(this).attr('id'));
                            if(jQuery(this).attr('id') == 'nav_overlay_id'){
                                value:jQuery("input[name=color_overlay_nav_bar]").val();
                            }
                       }
                   });
 }
});
```

Here input[name=color_overlay_nav_bar] has the opacity value, this needs to pre populate based on slider id.I have used `Create` event on document ready function to find id

But still i could not get it. something i missed here. What i done wrong on this.Kindly advice.

Thanks,
Dinesh

Comment: can you put your code on http://jsfiddle.net/ or give us live example of this code

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, my english is so bad. HEHEHE

You can't use "value" in "create" like this.

try this...

```
 $(function(){
      if($("input[name=color_overlay_nav_bar]").val() != '')
      { 

          $(".slider_global_style_overlay ").slider
          ({
              create: function(event, ui) 
              {
                    if($(this).attr('id') == 'nav_overlay_id'){
                        $(this).slider("value", $("input[name=color_overlay_nav_bar]").val());
                    }
              }
          })
      }

    });
```

OR

try this AFTER your the slide instance

```
if($("input[name=color_overlay_nav_bar]").val() != '')
{
    $("#nav_overlay_id").slider("value", $("input[name=color_overlay_nav_bar]").val());
}
```